# Mongoose OR operator for optional document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Jobs.find({status: 'active', expiry_date: {$gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, result) {})
```

I have above query that find active status and not expired. The logic just worked but it's broken for Jobs that doesn't have expiry_date document. This is due to the expiry_date document is a later added requirement.

How to still return the active Jobs if the expiry_date document not present?

Comment: Use the `$or` operator, combined with an `$exists` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the $or operator:

```
  Jobs.find({status: 'active', $or: [ {expiry_date: {$gt: Date.now()}}, {expiry_date: { $exists: false } ]}, function(err, result) {})
```

You might have to play with the existence query, since thatll match documents that don't have the field, but if a document has the field but it's null it won't.

Longer term, it'd actually be better to just fill in expiry dates for all your documents if you can.

Comment: longer term? I have 100 thousand of existing data. Anyway this is a good answer thanks! I think I'll update my document :D

Comment: Even more reason to fix it now if there is a way.